# how to construct a switch statement to run a function depending on if an element contains a particular class?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, conditional-statements

how do I convert the following to a switch statement?

```
if (event.target.classList.contains('ClassName')) {
    callFunction1()
} else if (event.target.classList.contains('anotherClassName')) {
    callFunction2()
}
```

where the html in question looks something like this:

```
<div class="ClassOne classTwo className"></div>
<div class="ClassThree classFour anotherClassName"></div>
```

I know this is incorrect but it gives an idea of what i'm trying to do.

```
switch (event.target) {
    case "className":
        function1(event.target)
        break
    case "anotherClassName":
        function2(event.target)
        break
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
switch (true) {
    case event.target.includes('className'):
        function1(event.target)
        break
    case event.target.includes('anotherClassName'):
        function2(event.target)
        break
}
```

But personally, I think that it is counter intuitive to use switch-statements this way. What's wrong with using `if` and `else if` in your case?

Comment: There are going to be a lot of conditions and usually switch statements are more readable in these situations.